# simple serial write and print in python

Tags: python

All i am doing is writing the numbers 80, 10, 150 where each takes a second to write, then printing it, but i get this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\desk\Downloads\serialTestPy_processing.py", line 10, in <module>
    decoded_bytes = float(ser_bytes[0:len(str(ser_bytes))-2].decode("utf-8"))
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

```
import serial
from time import sleep
ser = serial.Serial('COM4',19600)

while True:
    
    ser_bytes = ser.write(str.encode('80'))
    decoded_bytes = float(ser_bytes[0:len(str(ser_bytes))-2].decode("utf-8"))
    sleep(1)
    print(decoded_bytes)
    ser_bytes = ser.write(str.encode('10'))
    sleep(1)
    print(decoded_bytes)
    ser_bytes = ser.write(str.encode('150'))
    sleep(1)
    print(decoded_bytes)
```

Comment: `ser_bytes` is 2 or 3, the number of bytes written by each of your `ser.write()` calls.  Given that, the expression you're assigning to `decoded_bytes` makes no sense at all; what was that expected result?  I assume it was intended to either do something with the serial data just written (but you didn't store it anywhere), or the serial data just received (but you never read anything).

Comment: Yes, just remove all the lines where you assign or use `decoded_bytes`. These are doing nothing for your program. What's left will be doing the job of writing the strings you want with delays in-between.